# How can I improve this function using RXJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, rxjs

I'm new with RXJS and I would like to do a function which checks recursively a status until it will be "Available". I found this with vanilla JS to represent what I'm looking for:

```
setTimeout(() => {
                   this.updateStatus();
                 },status === 'Pending' ? 0 : 2000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mentioned you want to keep checking the status until it's available. I'm assuming you're looking for some kind of polling, but your code snippet with the the `setTimeout()` method will only run once after a delay and won't keep calling the `updateStatus` method. If you wanted to do a vanilla JS timer you'd need to look at using `setInterval()`

If you want to check every few seconds using rxjs, one solution could be to use the `timer`. The timer will emit an event every `period` milliseconds, after an initial delay of `delay` milliseconds. [See here for docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer)

You could do something along these lines:

```
timer(delay, interval)
  .pipe(
    tap(() => this.updateStatus())
    filter(() => this.status === 'Available'),
    take(1)
  ).subscribe(() => {
    console.log('Complete');
    //do work here
  });
```

This example uses the `tap` operator to call your `updateStatus` method every `interval` milliseconds after the initial delay has passed. Once your `status` var is set to `'Available'`, the observable will fire and the code in the `subscribe` block will be executed. The `take(1)` ensures that only one emission gets through once the status is no longer pending, so your observable will be closed and the timer will no longer have any active subscribers.

If your intent is to only check once, you can also use the `timer` to run once after a delay, similar to your `setTimeout()` example:

```
  timer(delay).subscribe(x => {
    this.updateStatus();
    //do something here.
  })
```